# Half or more elements order two implies generalized dihedral?

Tags: gr.group-theory

The "generalized dihedral group" for an abelian group *A* is the semidirect product of *A* and a cyclic group of order two acting via the inverse map on *A*. *A* thus has index two in the whole group and all elements outside *A* have order two. Thus, at least half the elements of any generalized dihedral group have order two.

My question is the converse: if half or more the elements of a finite group *G* have order two, is it necessary that *G* is either an elementary abelian 2-group or a generalized dihedral group? [Note: Actually nontrivial elementary abelian 2-groups are also generalized dihedral, they're an extreme case. Also, note that the direct product of a generalized dihedral group with an elementary abelian 2-group is still generalized dihedral, because the elementary abelian 2-group can be pulled inside the abelian part.]

I have a proof when the order of *G* is twice an odd number *m*. In that case, there is a short an elegant elementary proof -- we consider the set of elements that can be written as a product of two elements of order two and show that this is a subgroup of order *m*, then show that any element of order two acts by the inverse map on it, and hence the subgroup is abelian. It can also be thought of as a toy example of Frobenius' theorem on Frobenius subgroups and complements (though we don't need Frobenius' theorem).

However, I am having some difficulty generalizing this, mainly because there are elements of order two that are inside the abelian group.

Although I have a number of possible proof pathways, I'll refrain from mentioning them for now because the actual proof is likely to be much simpler and I don't want to bias others trying the problem.

Comment: It should be true. The property is preserved under homomorphisms. Then take the minimal non-trivial normal subgroup (which is a direct product of finite simple groups). The factor-group should be either elementary abelian or has an abelian subgroup of index 2, etc. I think it should be just a standard routine proof. 

Comment: @Tommasso: The Z/2Z can be pulled inside the abelian part, so a direct product of a generalized dihedral group with a Z/2Z is also generalized dihedral.

Comment: @Scott: I know. I just wrote the elementary abelian case separately because it is somewhat different, and also to avoid the "here's an obvious counterexample" comments/answers. But I'll clarify this in the question text.

Comment: @Vipul: you are right, sorry. I guess I was missing "generalized" in your conclusion

Comment: $D_8\times D_8$ ?

Comment: There is an actual classification of groups with at least half the elements being involutions; it was first done by Wall in "On Groups Consisting Mostly of Involutions".  A simpler treatment, though with a different goal in mind, is given in Liebeck and MacHale's paper "Groups with Automorphisms Inverting Most Elements".

Comment: Steve: Could you put this as an answer instead of a comment? Thanks!

Comment: Steve: Interesting. If I understand correctly the classification you point to, then $D_8 times D_8$ is essentially the only counterexample. The counterexamples seems to stem from the properties of small numbers (namely, that (3/4)^2 > 1/2) more than any intrinsic reason.

Comment: Well, there is also the central product of two $D_8$s, but yes, those are really the only counter-examples.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

$D_8\times D_8$ is such a group (it has 35 involutions) that fails to be either elementary abelian or generalized dihedral.

There is an actual classification of groups with at least half the elements being involutions; it was first done by Miller.  A modern reference would be the paper by Wall, ["On Groups Consisting Mostly of Involutions"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/abs/on-groups-consisting-mostly-of-involutions/554A7AE2A5C7B537B76CB098A8C6E2E2). A simpler treatment, though with a different goal in mind, is given in Liebeck and MacHale's paper ["Groups with Automorphisms Inverting Most Elements"](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01142582).

Comment: [Reposted comment from above] @Steve: Interesting. If I understand correctly the classification you point to, then $D_8 \times D_8$  is essentially the <em>only</em> counterexample (up to padding by an elementary abelian 2-group). The counterexamples seems to stem from the properties of small numbers (namely, that (3/4)^2 > 1/2) more than any intrinsic reason.

Comment: As you point out, in this comment, I missed the central product of two $D_8$s, which forms another class of examples. But these are not the only counterexamples to my conjecture -- there are a few others. There's a group of order 32 (GAP ID: 27) obtained as a semidirect product of an elementary abelian group of order 8 and an elementary abelian group of order 4 -- see http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/SmallGroup(32,27) for a description.

Comment: This is of the type "elementary abelian being acted on by element of order 2", specifically it is $(C_2)^4\rtimes C_2$.

Comment: This is detailed in Liebeck and MacHale's paper, under Type I*.

Comment: I think the real lesson here is that groups with orders a power of 2 are the bane of every group theorist's existence.

Comment: On the other hand, statistically every finite group is a 2-group...